# What is this strange sound under the MacBook Pro trackpad?

Tags: trackpad

I have been using my MacBook pro 15" since 2016. For the last two months, a **strange sound** is coming from the trackpad. Does anyone have any idea why this sound is coming? The sound can be heard from this Dropbox link.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/igfnzpsjwagevsf/Sound.m4a?dl=0

Comment: The first thing I check is to see that the battery is not swelling. You should be able to place a straightedge across the bottom case in the lower quadrant and it not rock back and forth.  Sans that the only other thing I can think of is dust and dirt accumulated under/around/within the mechanism.

Comment: When does this noise occur -- all the time, or while you're using the trackpad? And if you mute the speakers, do you still get the sound? Your Mac has very few moving parts -- principally the fans. I suppose it's conceivable that you've got sand (gravel!) in there. Either open it up yourself and give everything a good clean, or take it to an Apple Authorised Technician.

Comment: That sounds particularly bright & clear for a sound to be coming from *inside* a relatively closed structure. It sounds more like electrical interference… crackly speaker, or even a microphone motorboating. I suppose it could be a fan catching - for that you could maybe try iStat Menus & artificially ramp the fans faster, see if it changes the sound significantly.